# How can I copy drawings to other users in real time?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make a drawing program in JavaScript such that I and my friend draws the same picture at the same time? How can I move the picture from a www-site canvas to my friends www-browser?

Comment: You need a serverside language and you need to learn about [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

Comment: @epascarello which could be javascript

Comment: 1. Get a website.  2. Host a javascript canvas application with ajax responses sending draw data to and from the server. 3. Get your friend to go to said site. 4. ... 5. Profit (or maybe just some fun, near as can be realtime drawing action.

Comment: @epascarello not necessarily, he could use things like https://www.firebase.com/

Comment: Um @Jan.J Do you think that is running on magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it with http://socket.io/ 
There's some good tutorials around the web, I think there's also a thread here on stackoverflow. In my understanding, you have to create a drawing app that sends the user's interactions to the server. Or you could save the canvas as a data-url image and then send it to the server but that would be slower

Comment: That sounds reasonable. But I think I need also send the whole image in the case the original picture have not been done by my program. Or do I have to write a function that converts pictures to user interactions?

Comment: You could send a status of the image every 10 seconds to the server and save it. Once a user connects, you send him the last know status, so he doesn't start with a blank canvas.
Once he starts drawing, you don't send the image, but you send the user's interaction (for example: "the users drew a blue line from this point to that point") and then the server will send it to all the other people connected to the site. In fact it will send it to the user who just made a line as well, and then the frontend will render it to the canvas. If you do a couple of tutorials on websockets you'll understand

Answer (score 1):

basic premise:

**Drawing:** Create or find an script that allows you to draw on a canvas.

**Saving:** The canvas element has export options that allow the "picture" to be exported to, for example, a base 64 encoded png. You can then send that to the server to be stored.

**Retrieving:** Recall that saved image (using whatever method works for you) and then re-display it back in to browser.

Have a look at the [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement), specifically `toDataUrl` to get a value you can pass off to the server, then assign to another client's `<img src="..."/>`.

Here's a running start using an older draw utility and events, but can be easily ported to AJAX calls: http://jsfiddle.net/tL4Rr/2/

Comment: This would work but it would be incredibly slow as the browser would have to download a new image every time. Imagine doing it with a 1900 x 1200 image..

Comment: @JonasGrumann: Just one option. Not giving a fully refactored soltuion here, just getting OP's feet wet. I could get in to perpetual updates and PUSH notifications, but (IMHO) that's way outside the scope of the question.

Comment: as you are drawing in realtime you can send the raw data for ex. x:300 y:400 size:3 color:FFF, next point, ...

Comment: @Max: I'm aware of logistics, just not going to get in to details for such a vague question. The question itself is more about general approach then specifics. if they had provided code and their approach, I would offer fine tuning.

Comment: @Max: You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tL4Rr/1/)? (not refined so draw slow; also uses events and not AJAX, but easily ported). ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie exactly ;-)